# Enable socket interactor only when previous sockets are occupied

Tags: unity, c#, virtual-reality, unity-ui

There are 3 boxes and 3 socket interactors. I only want the second socket interactor to work when there is a box in socket one and the third to work when there is a box in the first and the second sockets. But I do not understand how to do it.

Comment: I've changed your question to ask about C#, since you probably don't want answers written in the UnityScript language that has not been supported by the engine for quite a few years now. Have you tried setting the socket interactor's `enabled` property to false when the condition is not met, and `true` when it is met, using events to update the condition when sockets have objects added/removed?

Comment: I get what you are saying can you write an example in code?